# If the order of an element $x$ is $36$, determine the order of the elements $x^{−1}$, $x^{−8}$, $x^{15}$ and $x^{27}$.

Tags: group-theory

If the order of an element $x$ is $36$, determine the order of the elements $x^{−1}$, $x^{−8}$, $x^{15}$ and $x^{27}$.

I’ve tried so far the question but as we know if an order of element $x$ is $36$
Then $x^{27}$ has an order $k$. So $x^{27k}=e$. So , $k>\frac 4 3$? This doesn’t sound right.

Please help me..

Answer (score 3):

The order of $x^{k}$ is the *least* $m$ such that $km=36n$ for some $n$. Therefore, $m$ is of the form $\frac{36}{k/n}$ ($*$), and $m=|x^{k}|$ ("the least") when the denominator in ($*$) is *the greatest* divisor of $k$ which is also a divisor of $36$, namely: $$m=\frac{36}{\operatorname{gcd}(k,36)} \tag 1$$

For instance, for $k=27$, $(1)$ yields $m=36/9=4$.

Answer (score 2):

The order of an element $x \in G$ is defined as the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $x^k= e$, the identity element of $G$.

If $x$ has order $36$, then it means that $x^{36h} = e$ for all integers $h$, and further that if $x^j=e$ then $j=36h$ (it is a multiple of $36$). This is an easy fact to prove (you have to use that the order is the *smallest* positive integer such that $x^k=e$).

So the question is: when is $(x^{27})^j$ a multiple of $36$? In other words, what is the least common multiple (l.c.m.) of $36$ and $27$? As I am sure you can compute, it is $108$. So the order of $x^{27}$ is $\frac{108}{27} = 4$.